# How to define a Result class which can be treated as boolean but has methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on adding further feature for a authentication module, for some reason, I cant change the interface, so the result should be used in some if..else condition.

I think I may need to define a Result class and return it's instance as result, this result can be treated as boolean so that the original projects which using this method will not be influenced and I can get the further info by calling method (for example: the reason of why validate is false). I think the following way can match my goal by return `true` or `false.define_method(:reason, proc[]{return reason})` but I think it's not a best way to do it.

Any idea is good idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Only `false` and `nil` are false values in Ruby, instance of your result class will definitely be true.
2. `true` and `false` are unique in Ruby. They are the only instance of `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`, respectively. Defining singleton methods on them will affect all other places using `true` or `false`. This may work in single threaded programs, but possibly not for multi threaded programs.

If the authentication API that you cannot change accepts only boolean values, I don't think you have good way to add further features while keeping backwards compatibility.